# editing a cell in an asp:datagrid

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

I have a asp:DataGrid which holds data in two columns on my webpage. The user can select a row for editing which I do by setting the value of “EditItemIndex” and rebinding the grid. What I would like to do now is restrict the editing to just one of the cells in the row rather than both. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the "ReadOnly" attribute of the column that you don't want to edit, to true.

```
<asp:BoundColumn HeaderText="UserName" DataField="UserName" ReadOnly="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You could convert the BoundColumn into a TemplateField and change the text box to readonly or replace the text box with a label in the EditItemTemplate. A template field will give you a little more flexibility.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridView1" runat="server">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```